# Which part of the hybridauth information can be used to authenticate against a REST web service?

Tags: rest, slim, hybridauth

i'm leveraging hybridauth for my frontend authentication only w/ google currently. To be more precise i have a frontend.php and an login.php.

- The frontend.php is only checking if there is an active connection (i.e. Hybrid_Auth::isConnectedWith(provider)) otherwise redirect to the login.php.
- The user can then login in the login.php and if successful will be redirected again to the frontend.php. This works fine. I also do already store the hybridauth session in the DB.

My questions:

- My frontend.php + JS is purely communicating with the backend via REST. Currently my REST endpoints do NOT authenticate. Which part of the successful frontend login hybridauth information can i send to the REST backend (as part of the request body or header e.g.) to be sure this can't be manipulated? Send the hybridauth session and compare it in the backend if this exists in the DB, is this right?
- The [documentation](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/HybridAuth_Sessions.html) says that it's more convinient to store sessions in a DB. This is now done in my login.php. Should i keep old connections in my DB or can i DELETE them if i INSERT a new one?

  - Also for convinience, i could store the "AppInternal"UserId in a cookie, as suggested in the comments, to do the DB lookup for the session. But if i do so, could this be manipulated? If a client would go to login and pretend to be user #1 (cookie manipulation: i.e. UserID=1), my logic would retrieve the last session for this UserID=1 - even if this client is someone else. Is this then validated again in hybridauth?